# Can't block google logo in squid

Tags: squid

I wanted to block google logo via Squid proxy:

[image]

So I added this line to block.acl:

```
google\..+/logos/.+
```

in squid.conf I have this:

```
acl bad_domain dstdom_regex "/etc/squid/block.acl"
acl good_domain dstdom_regex "/etc/squid/white.acl"

http_access deny bad_domain
http_access allow good_domain
http_access deny all
```

But the image is still not blocked: https://www.google.ru/logos/doodles/2013/doctor-whos-50th-anniversary-6317003539218432-res.png.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given their docs:

- http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#The_Basics:_How_the_parts_fit_together

> dstdom_regex: destination (server) regular expression pattern matching

This should match only the server (i.e. the `www.google.ru` part in your example), while you want to use it to block a specific URL (i.e. server + path). I think you need to use this:

> url_regex: URL regular expression pattern matching

instead. See e.g. this example from the above docs:

- http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#How_can_I_allow_a_single_address_to_access_a_specific_URL.3F

where it says:

```
acl special_client src 10.1.2.3
acl special_url url_regex ^http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/FAQ/$
http_access allow special_client special_url
http_access deny special_url
```

This obviously an allow specification, but the same should hold for the deny specification you are after.

Comment: Important thing: you must deny URLs before `http_access allow good_domain`, where you allow them.